# Display: table-cell problems in chrome while working fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css

I develop html code using table tag and its working fine in all other browser like safari, Firefox, IE etc, but code not working for chrome as result output as displayed in following attached image.
[image]

```css
.contfull {
  max-height: 900px;
}
body {
  background: #cbd0d4 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container_q {
  background: #f0efef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.header_q {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e0dcdc;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.logo_q {
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo_q a {
  outline: medium none;
}
.contfull {
  background: #f0efef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
}
.btncross {
  float: right;
}
.btncross a {
  background: #fff url("../imagesSurvey/cross-img.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 27px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 27px;
}
.btncross a:hover {
  background: #e5e5e5 url("../imagesSurvey/cross-img.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
}
.btncross a.min {
  background-position: 5px 7px;
}
.btncross a.clobtn {
  background-position: -17px 7px;
}
.redcol {
  color: #ff0800;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 10px;
}
a {
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) {
  float: left;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 28px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not(old) + label {
  background-position: 0 -64px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) + label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://publish.adsys2.bonzaii.no/imagesSurvey/checks.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 34px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  background: #efefef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
  width: 99%;
}
textarea {
  background: #efefef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 70px;
  outline: medium none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
  width: 99.5%;
}
input[type="radio"]:not(old) {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 28px;
}
input[type="radio"]:not(old) + label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://publish.adsys2.bonzaii.no/imagesSurvey/checks.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -112px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 0;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:not(old) + label {
  background-position: 0 -180px;
}
button {
  background: #272727 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: "gothammediumwebfont";
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: none;
}
button:focus {
  background: #2e2e2e none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
button:hover {
  background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
a.nextbtn {
  background: #272727 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: "gothammediumwebfont";
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-transform: none;
}
a.nextbtn:focus {
  background: #2e2e2e none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
a.nextbtn:hover {
  background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
a.skipbtn {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #444444;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: "gothammediumwebfont";
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
}
a.skipbtn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
select {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
label.pos {
  background: #efefef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
label.yearwise {
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 18%;
}
label.pos::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../imagesSurvey/arrow-top.png") no-repeat scroll 0 center;
  border-left: 1px solid #e7e6e6;
  color: #444;
  font-family: "GothamBook";
  padding: 8px 14px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: 1px;
}
label.pos {
  background: #efefef none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
}
label.pos::before {
  background: #efefef url("../imagesSurvey/arrow-top.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 44px;
}
span.radiaspace {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 2px;
  width: 20px;
}
span {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #444444;
  font-family: "gothammediumwebfont";
}
.simplehead {
  color: #444444;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
}
.section {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px -1px #dedddd;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 96%;
}
.section:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.qa {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.qa li {
  background: #fff url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom;
  line-height: 2em;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.qa li:hover {
  background: #efefef url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom;
}
.qa li a {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.radioquestion li {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.year {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
ul.radpart {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.radpart li {
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 13px 0 10px 20px;
}
ul.longques {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.longques li {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
  background-position: center bottom, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.longques li:first-child {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
  background-position: center bottom, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
.longques li:first-child:hover {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
  background-position: center bottom, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
.longques li:last-child {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.longques li:last-child:hover {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.longques li:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
  background-position: center bottom, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
.longques li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
.longques li span:last-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.group::before,
.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group::after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {} .span_3_of_3 {
  width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
  width: 49.6%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
  width: 32.2%;
}
.span_1_of_1 {
  width: 25%;
}
.span_4_of_1 {
  width: 49.6%;
}
.span_4_of_2 {
  width: 49.6%;
}
.span_5_of_2 {
  width: 100%;
}
p {} .longques li div {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
  background-position: center bottom, center top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
  padding: 11px 10px;
}
.secure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.secure ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}
.secure li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.secure li span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png") repeat-y scroll right bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
}
.namefile {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.ques {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 1%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 43%;
}
.ques:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7 url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom;
}
.tohide {
  display: none;
}
.empty_div {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.answered {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.answered:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  opacity: 1;
}
.survey-lite .next {
  background-position: 8px 7px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #c7c7c7;
  top: 58px;
}
.survey-lite .prev {
  background-position: 8px -22px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #c7c7c7;
}
.survey-lite .prev:hover {
  background-position: 8px -22px;
}
.survey-lite .next:hover {
  background-position: 8px 7px;
}
.survey-lite a,
.survey-lite a:visited {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff url("../imagesSurvey/icon-arrowdown.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -22px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.survey-lite {} .survey-lite a:hover {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff url("../imagesSurvey/icon-arrowdown.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}
.survey-lite .next,
.survey-lite .prev {
  display: none;
}
.radbtn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40px;
}
.required {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 52px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: absolute;
}
.section1 {
  border-radius: 7px;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 93%;
}
.selectIncdate {
  width: 100% !important;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix("") {
  .contfull {
    width: 60.5%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  label.yearwise {
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 25%;
  }
  .namefile {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 35%;
  }
  .ques {
    padding: 0;
    width: 65%;
  }
  .secure ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .longques li {
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
    background-position: center bottom, right top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .secure li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 18% !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
  }
  .span_3_of_3,
  .span_2_of_3,
  .span_1_of_3,
  .span_1_of_1,
  .span_5_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  label.yearwise {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 99% !important;
  }
  .span_4_of_1 {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 26.6%;
  }
  .span_4_of_2 {
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: 67.6%;
  }
  .radpart li {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    height: 64px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 7px 0 3px !important;
  }
  ul.radpart {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 45px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .contfull {
    display: block;
    padding: 4%;
    width: 92%;
  }
  .namefile {
    min-height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .ques {
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
    background-position: center bottom, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .ques:hover {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
    background-position: center bottom, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
  }
  .secure li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
    width: 50px !important;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 98.5%;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 98.5%;
  }
}
@-moz-document url-prefix("") {
  @media (max-width: 2500px) {
    .contfull {
      width: 99.2%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .contfull {
      width: 96.2%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .contfull {
      width: 99.2%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .contfull {
      width: 96% !important;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .contfull {
      width: 96% !important;
    }
  }
}
.survey-lite .next,
.survey-lite .prev {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.rwd-table tr:hover {
  background: #efefef none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
td.surveyquest {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table th:last-child {
  background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.rwd-table td::before {
  content: attr(data-th)" ";
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 6.5em;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:first-child {
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td:first-child::before {
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td {
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), none;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .rwd-table td.borderrad span.radbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40px;
  }
  .rwd-table td::before {
    content: attr(data-th)" ";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  td.surveyquest {
    float: none;
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 2px 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child,
  .rwd-table td:first-child {
    background-image: none, none;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child,
  .rwd-table td:last-child {
    background-image: url("../imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), none;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table {
    color: #444444;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .rwd-table tr {
    border-color: #46627f;
    display: table-row;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td {
    margin: 0.5em 1em;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .rwd-table th,
  .rwd-table td::before {
    color: #444444;
  }
  td.surveyquest {
    height: auto;
    padding: 4px 0 !important;
  }
}
.borderrad {
  background-image: url("http://publish.adsys2.bonzaii.no/imagesSurvey/line-img.png"), url("http://publish.adsys2.bonzaii.no/imagesSurvey/line-img-v.png");
  background-position: center bottom, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Simple HTML5 blog</title>

<head></head>

<body>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container_q">

      <div class="contfull" style="width:700px !important;">
        <div style="display: block; margin-top: 0px;" class="section group tohide" id="question_6">
          <div class="col span_3_of_3">
            <div class="simplehead">
              <div>Hvor godt mener du at fÃ¸lgende pÃ¥stander om artiklene i Skeidars kundemagasin stemmer? (1 = stemmer overhode ikke, 5 = stemmer veldig godt)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col span_3_of_3">
            <table class="rwd-table">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <!--THIS CODE LIST OPTIONS NUMBER/TEXT-->
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">1</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">2</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">3</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">4</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">5</th>
                  <th class="borderrad">Ingen oppfatning</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- END HERE -->

                <tr>
                  <td data-th="&nbsp;" class="surveyquest">Artiklene henvender seg til meg</td>
                  <td data-th="1" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="1_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="1" type="radio"><label for="1_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="2" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="2_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="2" type="radio"><label for="2_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="3" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="3_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="3" type="radio"><label for="3_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="4" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="4_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="4" type="radio"><label for="4_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="5" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="5_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="5" type="radio"><label for="5_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Ingen oppfatning" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="6_32964120" name="radio_32964120" value="Ingen oppfatning" type="radio"><label for="6_32964120"></label></span>
                  </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <td data-th="&nbsp;" class="surveyquest">Artiklene ga meg ny informasjon</td>
                  <td data-th="1" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="1_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="1" type="radio"><label for="1_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="2" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="2_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="2" type="radio"><label for="2_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="3" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="3_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="3" type="radio"><label for="3_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="4" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="4_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="4" type="radio"><label for="4_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="5" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="5_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="5" type="radio"><label for="5_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Ingen oppfatning" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="6_32991258" name="radio_32991258" value="Ingen oppfatning" type="radio"><label for="6_32991258"></label></span>
                  </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <td data-th="&nbsp;" class="surveyquest">Artiklene er velskrevne</td>
                  <td data-th="1" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="1_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="1" type="radio"><label for="1_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="2" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="2_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="2" type="radio"><label for="2_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="3" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="3_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="3" type="radio"><label for="3_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="4" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="4_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="4" type="radio"><label for="4_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="5" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="5_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="5" type="radio"><label for="5_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Ingen oppfatning" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="6_33018395" name="radio_33018395" value="Ingen oppfatning" type="radio"><label for="6_33018395"></label></span>
                  </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <td data-th="&nbsp;" class="surveyquest">Artiklene er inspirerende</td>
                  <td data-th="1" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="1_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="1" type="radio"><label for="1_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="2" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="2_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="2" type="radio"><label for="2_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="3" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="3_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="3" type="radio"><label for="3_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="4" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="4_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="4" type="radio"><label for="4_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="5" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="5_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="5" type="radio"><label for="5_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Ingen oppfatning" class="borderrad"><span class="radbtn"> <input id="6_33045532" name="radio_33045532" value="Ingen oppfatning" type="radio"><label for="6_33045532"></label></span>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/xum56ae1/)

Comment: where is the code? A fiddle could do

Comment: Do you have any code for this :)

Comment: you want to see html...

Comment: The CSS you've provided does not suffice to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually problem only with {display: table-cell;} CSS property it do not work with chrome(window) only, while working fine with rest browser and even with chrome Linux version also working fine...

Comment: Cannot reproduce at my Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m

Comment: ok give me time I prepare code so you can understand the problem...  Many Thanks you all

Comment: Please Check code over JsFiddle URL : http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/xum56ae1/

Comment: Connot reproduce - Chrome Version 46.0.2490.22 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: what you mean Paulie ?

Comment: I have uploaded html over jsfiddle please get from there html

Comment: Dear All Issue has been fixed... problem was in  with this [ td.surveyquest {height: 30px !important; overflow:auto !important; overflow-x:hidden !important; float: left;  padding: 0px !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-size:14px;} ] it was override the css..      Many Thanks for your efforts and response..

Comment: Please check your css file, may be some styles overriding.

Comment: Sunny, this question sat here for 3 months, then last night an Answer came in "Please check your css file, may be some styles overriding" by [Jatin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5209147/jatin-kalra) , an answer that was later converted to a comment by a mod. That answer was almost immediately upvoted twice and marked Accepted Answer. Seems interesting. Since you told everyone in comments how you fixed it, perhaps answer your own question, mark it, and clear the decks of it

Comment: Yes bro I accept my mistake.. someone need reputation to start stackoverflow account so I did this... I am really sorry for this

Comment: In newer version of chrome, it works well. I had same issues previously and now without any hacks the property Display: table-cell works well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should avoid using "!important" that often.
Have you tried using the table-layout:fixed property?

In your case I would say something like:

```
.rwd-table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

Adding another table to wrap only the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted there is some stray text.  After the final `</tr>` you have the letters `ur`.  Is that in the real page?  if so, that would cause the browser to act funny when rendering the table, since the text is not contained within any table element.

It may just be a typo from copying and pasting your code, but I've made mistakes like that when dealing with tables and have seen it cause problems so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: The original asker found the solution and posted their answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution may be its helps you.

Here is your solution..

```
td.surveyquest {
    height: 30px !important; 
    overflow:auto !important; 
    overflow-x:hidden !important; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 0px !important; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    font-size:14px;
 }
```

It was override the css. Try to avoid use of  **!important** every time. Used it when it's necessary.  Also check your css code for if some code override or not.

Comment: agreed, !important should not use every time